# New-RDSessionDeployment command does not execute when run from Chef recipe

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, rds

There is a Chef recipe which uses powershell_script to run the commands to deploy Remote Desktop Session.

```
powershell_script 'Test_RDSessionDeloyment' do
  code <<-EOH
  Import-Module RemoteDesktop
  New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker <ConnectionBrokerMachine> -SessionHost <SessionHost>
  EOH
  user "domainadmin"
  password "*******"
end
```

Above mentioned commands work fine when it is run as separate powershell script (test.ps1). But when run through Chef's resource powershell_script, it would spin up a new powershell window and progress bar which says Validation in progress and ends the execution without completing deployment.

Can someone tell us what is the issue here and how do we run these commands via chef recipe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see when you execute chef-client with [`-l debug`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html)?

Comment: I tried running with -l debug

`WARNING: This module requires Administrator privileges. Please restart this session in elevated mode.
Validation failed for the "RD Connection Broker" parameter.
<ConnectionBrokerMachine>    Unable to connect to the server by using Windows PowerShell remoting. V
erify that you can connect to the server.[2019-09-27T06:27:15+00:00] INFO: powershell_script[Test_RDSessionDeloyment] ra
n successfully`

When tried with elevated mode, 
`NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `elevated' for Chef::Resource::PowershellScript`

Comment: i will advise you to use [`--fatal-windows-admin-check`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html) and make sure you [run with elevated privileges](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#windows) correctly